# Java - Polynomial function reading hexadecimal Strings as ASCII

Tags: java

I have a function that is supposed to read a hex number, but it is not reading it correctly. The polynomial function is reading the string as ASCII instead of hex.

Here is the portion of code that is doing the work:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Calculate");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String str = textArea.getText();

                      int crc = 0xFFFF;        
                     int polynomial = 0x1021;  

                        byte bytes[] = str.getBytes();
                     for (byte b : bytes) {
                         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                             boolean bit = ((b   >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
                             boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15    & 1) == 1);
                             crc <<= 1;
                             if (c15 ^ bit) crc ^= polynomial;
                          }
                     }
                     crc &= 0xFFFF;
                textField.setText(""+Integer.toHexString(crc));
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(10, 245, 90, 25);
        panel.add(button);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.getBytes gives you the characters with the default character encoding.  It is not recomended evenm if you want to encode a String as bytes (it is suggest you provide the encoding you want)

In this pase you want to parse your hexidecimal string into bytes. A simple way to do this is to use BigInteger.

```
String hex = "CAFEBABE";
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray();
if (bytes.length > 0 && bytes[0] == 0)
    bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 1, bytes.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

prints

```
[-54, -2, -70, -66]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you to all who responded, the BigInteger worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, String.getBytes() gets you the bytes of the ascii string. 
Try [Integer.decode(str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) , assuming that the string starts with "0x", or prepend it yourself.

Comment: This still limits the input to whatever an int can hold, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte bytes[] = str.getBytes();
```

The above line uses your platform's default encoding to transform characters to bytes. So if it's ASCII and your hex string is `A1`, you will get the ASCII value of A followed by the ASCII value of 1.

Use a Hex encoder/decoder to transform the string to bytes. I like [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html), but Apache [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) also has an implementation. You can also of course implement your own as [Peter Lawrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093005/571407) shows.

Comment: parseInt won't parse hex with the top bit set.  You can use Long.ParseLong() and cast it.